# Google Sheets: Add editors via script in Protected Sheet and Ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

May I ask if how can I add the editors via script to the permissions in the **protected sheets & ranges**? I tried to used `protection.addEditors();` and it needs to enumerate all the email addresses, right? But, is there an easy or another way for me to do this? I have 90 sheets to modify one by one if there is no other way. Email addresses are not the same for each file.

I'm thinking of automatically getting all the editors in the **share with people and groups** option in Google drive. Is this possible to do?

[image: Share with people & groups]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want to programmatically retrieve the list of editors for a series of spreadsheets, in order to add them as editors of a [Protected](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) sheet or range (not sure why you want to add this protection, since by default the file editors will be the only ones who will be able to edit the spreadsheet, but whatever suits you).

#### Solution - File.getEditors():

You can retrieve this list by getting the [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) via [DriveApp.getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) and, for each `File`, getting the list of editors via [File.getEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geteditors).

#### Code snippet:

```
function addEditors() {
  const spreadsheetIDs = ["spreadsheet_ID_1", "spreadsheet_ID_2", ... etc.];
  spreadsheetIDs.forEach(spreadsheetID => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);
    const editors = file.getEditors();
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
    spreadsheet.addEditors(editors);
  });
}
```

Comment: `.getEditors()` helps! Thank you!